# Define convergence of series (criterion of Weierstrass)

Tags: convergence-divergence

Using the criterion of Weierstrass define convergence of series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}n!}{n^{2n} }\cos2nx$$
$x\in R$

Comment: The terms approach $0$ very rapidly, so there is no convergence issue.

Answer (score 18):

Find sequence $A_{n}$  which satisfy the inequality:

$\vert f_{n}\vert \le A_{n}$

$$\left|\frac {(-1)^{n+1}n!}{n^{2n} }\ \cos(2nx) \right|\le \frac{n!}{n^{2n}}$$

Now define the convergence of series:
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{n^{2n}}$

Use D'Alambert's criterion:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{A_{n+1}}{A_{n}}
= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(n+1)n!}{(n+1)^{2(n+1)}}\frac{n^{2n}}{n!}
= \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{2n}\frac{1}{n+1}=0<1$$

$$
\left\{
\lim_{n \to \infty}(\frac{n}{n+1})^{2n}
    =\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{n+1-1}{n+1}\right)^{2n}
    = e^{-2} \right\}
$$

Under D’Alambert criterion we find that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{n^{2n}}$  is convergent.

so

Under the criterion of Weierstrass we find that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}n!}{n^{2n} }\ \cos (2nx)$ is uniformly convergent for $x\in R$.